# Error navigating between pages with async data with react-router

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-router

So basically sometimes when I scroll between pages with React-router and I go try to go to a page with async code that runs as the lifecycle runs (componentDidMount) it throws me an error saying you can't map a state of 'null'.

question is.. how can I prevent that from happening when navigating between pages?

Example (Dashboard)

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovies();
        this.props.fetchSeries();
    }
    handleFetchMovies() {
        if(this.props.assets.fetchMoviesError) {
            return (
                <div className="loading">
                    <h1>{this.props.assets.fetchMoviesError}</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else if(this.props.assets.loadingMovies) {
            return (
                <div className="loading">
                    <h1>Loading...</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return this.props.assets.latestMovies.map(movie => {
                const movieURL = movie.title.split(' ').join('+').toLowerCase().trim();
                return (
                        <div className="latest" key={movie._id}>
                            <Link to={`/movie/${movieURL}`}>
                                <div className="asset-cover" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${movie.poster})` }}></div>
                            </Link>
                            <h1><Link to={`/movie/${movieURL}`}>{movie.title}</Link></h1>
                            <Link to={`/sort/years/${movie.year }`}>{movie.year}</Link>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

whenever I go from this page to a different page and try to go back to it it says

> this.props.assets.latestMovies.map is not a function

because the componentDidMount function didn't run.

Comment: Can you include the component class or piece of code thats causing the error and the exact error message please? :)

Comment: hey @ShawnAndrews I did add it now, I'm sorry for being so late I was out of city. :)